# Moving Snake in C

Tags: c, linked-list

We're creating a snake game on an STM32 discovery board, and displaying it on an LED screen. We're storing the snake in a linked list type of structure. We got the collision detection stuff down, and we know how to move the head of the snake, but we don't know how to grow it. Can you give us any pointers?

Here's what we have:

```
void move_seg() {
  struct seg *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct seg));
  temp->x = head->x + xdir[direction]*4;
  temp->y = head->y + ydir[direction]*4;
  head->next = temp;
  head = temp;
  draw_seg(head, WHITE);
  //check if snake collided with itself..
  collision_detection();
  //check if apple was eaten
  apple_eaten();
  if (apple_was_eaten) { 
    draw_seg(tail, WHITE);
  }
  else { 
    draw_seg(tail, BLACK);
  }
  tail = tail->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: If the snake grows, then all you need to do is **not** remove the tail square of the snake, right?

Comment: Just add on to the head without moving the tail.

Comment: @immibis: That's what we thought we were doing- when the apple's eaten, we're drawing the tail and not removing it afterwards. When it's not eaten, we draw over the tail with the background color

Comment: @mdegges What does `tail = tail->next;` do?

Comment: @immibis: I think it should just update the tail when a new node is added

Comment: it seems you got the list in the reverse order of links, tail to head. To not grow the snake, just move the `tail=tail->next` inside the `else` block. Also, check for memory leaks, you should free the memory there, too.

Comment: Linked list? Really? How about a circular buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post an update to show what we did. It was a pretty simple fix once we added a prev pointer to the seg structure and created a matrix of the size of the board to store where apples/snake segments are.

We only delete the tail when the head doesn't collide with an apple.

```
void move_seg() {
  //get head's next position, set that as new head
  seg* next_head = malloc(sizeof(seg));
  next_head->x = (head->x + xdir[direction] + 24) % 24;
  next_head->y = (head->y + ydir[direction] + 32) % 32;
  next_head->prev = 0;
  next_head->next = head;
  head->prev = next_head;
  head = next_head;

  int delete_tail = 1;

  //check if head collided with apple
  if (board[head->x][head->y] == HAS_APPLE) {
    //if so, delete tail, create new apple
    delete_tail = 0;
    create_apple();
  }

  //check if head collided with any other part of the snake
  if (board[head->x][head->y] == HAS_SNAKE) {
    //if so, game over
    game_over = 1;
  }

  //draw the head, add it to the matrix
  draw_seg(head, WHITE);
  board[head->x][head->y] = HAS_SNAKE;

  //if the snake didn't collide with an apple 
  if (delete_tail) {
    //delete the tail
    board[tail->x][tail->y] = 0;
    seg* temp = tail;
    tail = temp->prev;
    tail->next = 0;
    draw_seg(temp, BLACK);
    //free(temp);
  }
}
```